# Java issues with garage application

Tags: remote-desktop, java, sun-java6-jdk

A customer uses a specific garage application. It started complaining few days ago. Error on the screen says that Java 7 32-bit is not installed. Third party (software devop) also points to a Java issue.
The customer uses a Remote Desktop Gateway that loadbalances between 3 RD servers. **2 of them don't have the problem.** There is nowhere Java 7 32-bit installed. So I permitted myself to doubt about the credibility of the error message.

Some info: IMPORTANT => RD2 is the problem server

RD-01

```
C:\Windows\system32>java -version
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
```

RD-02

```
C:\Windows\System32>java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.11.9.1 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.11.9.1 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

RD-03

```
C:\Windows\system32>java -version
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)
```

**I clearly see the difference on RD-02.** Actions till now but not helping:

Changed behaviour of .jar files in default program to Java(TM) Platform SE Binary (like it is on RD-01 and RD-03).

On the installed applications list in System => Apps & Features I have this:

RD-01

[image]

RD-02

[image]

RD-03

[image]

This confuses me a lot because RD-01 and RD-02 are totally the same. And from where comes that openJDK software from the output in cmd?

Next step I will do is looking into a software that they use and it's called OpenWebStart. It seems to be a Java kind of software. RD-01 and RD-03 are running OpenWebStart version 1.3.0 while RD-02 is running version 1.4.0.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: _"RD-01 and RD-03 are running OpenWebStart version 1.3.0 while RD-02 is running version 1.4.0."_ - try to downgrade. Java 8 may be installed on RD-2, but the `java` you've called is Java 11. Check the `%PATH%`.

Comment: @gronostaj you've put it on the right track. Found my solution for this evening after business hours. Thanks. Should I edit my post or Answer my own question? Referring to you of course.

Comment: Please post an answer. Self-answering is welcome in our format. And thanks for asking before editing the solution into your question!

Answer (score 0):

Like gronostaj suggested looking for the path send me in the right direction.
With a command found in a Google search I found the software that provided the output of RD-02.

```
C:\Windows\System32>for %i in (javac.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.11_9\bin\javac.exe
```

I uninstalled Amazon Corretto that was not installed on RD-01 and RD-03. Probably someone installed it together with another software.

After that the command java -version returned me an output like RD-01 and RD-03. The problem with the software was also resolved.

```
C:\Windows\System32>java -version
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
```